# Representing $x$ as a linear combination of higher powers $x^n$

Tags: approximation-theory

Applying the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) on $[0,1]$ repeatedly, we can represent
$$
x= \sum_{n\geq 2} c_n x^n
$$ 
as a uniformly convergent series (**edit:** only over some subsequence, see edits below) on $[0,1]$ of higher powers $x^n$ for $n\geq 2$. What can one say about the coefficients? Is there an explicit choice of $c_n$?

**Edit:** Comments below suggest that this is not possible. What is wrong with the following argument? Take $\epsilon>0$ and approximate $x$ by a finite combination of higher powers and a constant uniformly with an error $\epsilon/2.$ Plugging  $x=0$ we see that the constant is smaller than $\epsilon/2$ so dropping it we get an approximation up to $\epsilon$ by a finite sum $\sum_{n=2}^{N_1} c_n x^n.$ Next, consider $x-\sum_{n=2}^{N_1} c_n x^n$ and approximate it by a linear combination $\sum_{n=N_1+1}^{N_2} c_n x^n$ up to an error $\epsilon/2.$ This gives us an $\epsilon/2$-approximation $\sum_{n=1}^{N_2}c_n x^n.$ Continue this construction repeatedly.

**Edit II:** Theorem holds for $a=0$ if we include constants, but Robert Israel's comment below contained the main point: the series only converges over some subsequence $(N_k)_{k\geq 1}$ as in the above construction. Let me rephrase the question accordingly:

Is there anything interesting one can say about $c_n$? Can one choose the subsequence and $c_n$ in a way that $(c_n)\in\ell^p$ for some $p$, or uniformly bounded?

Comment: can you perhaps shed some light onto how this might work near $x=0$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker It won't work - the theorem only holds on intervals $[a,b]$ with $a>0$.

Comment: You can't get a convergent series, either: only some subsequence of the partial sums converges.

Comment: As has been pointed out, a convergent series would define a holomorphic function near $x=0$, which cannot have two distinct power series representations. The problem with your argument is that the $c_n$'s will depend on $\epsilon$, so you're not constructing a series at all but a more general sequence of polynomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be in $\ell^p$ or bounded, in fact you can't have $|c_n| = O(t^{-n})$ for any $t > a$ where the subsequence converges on $[a,1]$. This is because if $|c_n| = O(t^{-n})$, $\sum_n c_n z^n$ is analytic in $|z|<t$, and by uniqueness...

Answer (score 2):

[Sorry -- too long for a comment]. It has already been pointed out that if you want 0 in your domain then you'll have to use constant functions too. But even then the theorem does not say what you seem to think it says: it only says that we can approximate $f(x)=x$ arbitrarily well by such a power series -- and as the approximation gets better and better the terms might jump around like crazy. In particular the coefficients are not really well-defined. As one way of seeing this, take one expansion which is very close to $x$ and let's assume the coefficient of $x^7$ is non-zero. Then remove 7 from your set of allowable powers of $x$ and the theorem again says that one can approximate $x$ arbitrarily well; this time the coefficient of $x^7$ is forced to be zero.

Comment: What is wrong with the argument I sketched in my edit?

Comment: @C.Eratosthene As Dirk points out, the theorem holds only on intervals $[a,b]$ with $a>0$. Your arguments actually show why this condition is necessary.

Comment: Robert Israel's objection is the point -- your resulting infinite series is not guaranteed to converge. You only know that it's well-behaved if you sum up to $N_1$, $N_2$ and so on. The intermediate sums will presumably be all over the place.

Comment: In fact one can I guess see this by fixing $N$ and then looking at behaviour for $x=\delta$ chosen so small that $x$ is far larger than $\sum_{i=1}^Nc_ix^i$. This then shows that some term beyond the $N$th term has to be gigantic.